# Regex Match for HTML string with newline

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match:

```
    <h4>Manufacturer</h4>\n\n  Gigabyte\n\n\n
```

My Regex ATM is:

```
    Match regex = Regex.Match(cleanedUpHtml, "Manufacturer(.*?)\n\n\n", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

However it does not work.

The (.*?) should match all in between.

Comment: regex stops matching when it sees new line, which means it stopped when it saw the first \n and then found no 3 consecutive \n. And then it jumps to the next line and found no "Manufacturer" so no match again

Comment: How do I solve this? Can I tell it to not ignore \n?

Comment: I dont know if you could. But it would be very expensive operation if it doesnt so I can see why it is behaving that way

Comment: Are you sure you have "\n" but not "\r\n"?

Comment: To have `.` match `\n` you need the [`RegexOptions.Singleline`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) option enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 things I find important:

1. Whenever you declare a regex pattern in C#, it is advisable to use string literals, i.e. `@"PATTERN"`. This simplifies writing regex patterns.
2. `RegexOptions.Singleline` must be used to treat multiline text as a string, i.e. a dot will match a line break.

Here is my code snippet:

```
var str = "<h4>Manufacturer</h4>\n\n  Gigabyte\n\n\n";
var regex = Regex.Match(str, @"Manufacturer(.*?)\n\n\n", 
             RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
if (regex.Success)
    MessageBox.Show("\"" + regex.Value + "\"");
```

The `regex.Value` is

```
"Manufacturer</h4>

  Gigabyte


"
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced \n with another value and then Regex searched my replaced value. It is working for the time being, but it may not be the best approach. Any recommendations appreciated.

```
    cleanedUpHtml = cleanedUpHtml.Replace("\n", "p19o9");
    Match regex = Regex.Match(cleanedUpHtml, "Manufacturer(.*?)p19o9p19o9p19o9", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally I prefere to cleanup the string from html tags and new-line characters before using the regex.

`(.*?)` stops capture with \n characer, you might use a more generic group instead, like `([\w|\W]*?)`